# Simple Code Igniter Controller and Model causing a 500 error - no CI error shown

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've just started learning Code Igniter and I've run in to a problem almost straight away.

Using the code below and a database setup with the correct privileges I get a 500 error (server error). CI is not throwing an error and I can't see anything wrong with this code.

I'm using the latest version of CI and testing this code:

Controller: products.php

```
class Products extends CI_Controller {

public function index() {
    $this->load->model('products');
    $this->load->view('products');
}
}
```

Model: products.php

```
class Products extends CI_Model {
    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_products() {
        $q = $this->db->get('product');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
}
```

I've put these classes in the directories they should be in with a filename of the same name as the class....if I comment out the load-model code in the controller my view is shown. My database connections are correct because if I change them to something incorrect CI throws an error. There's some sort of problem with the model or the loading of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have conflicting class names, the modell and the controller class both called `Products`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

class Products extends CI_Controller {

```
public function index() {
    $this->load->model('products_model','products');
    $this->load->view('products');
}
}
```

Model: products_model.php

```
class Products extends CI_Model {
                        function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
    }

    function get_products() {
        $q = $this->db->get('product');
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A good convention to use is to name your controller ProductsController and then leave the model Products. So all controllers are SomethingController.

Example:

```
class ProductsController extends CI_Controller
```

where the filename become products_controller.php

and the model remains:

```
class Products extends CI_model
```

and remains products.php

Now your code should work.

Comment: 'ProductsController' would not make much since in the URI.  Best practice is to reserve short names for controllers, to eliminate the need for massive routing tables (for SEO sake), and use _model and _library to declare conflicting classes.

Comment: If you use proper routing this is not an issue.

Comment: ?? What do you consider proper routing?

Comment: Well you can easily use a regex or wildcard in the routes.php file looking for *Controller. You can also do this in your htaccess files with a regex. The routes.php docs are here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

Comment: For example (not tested) something like this in your route $route['([a-z]+)Controller'] = "$1";

Comment: Fair enough.  I guess REGEX is spooled for the router anyways, might as well use it.